# prometheus/blackbox_exporter return 403

Tags: prometheus, http-redirect, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have setup prometheus/blackbox_exporter with following config

```
    modules:
      http_2xx:
        prober: http
        timeout: 5s
        http:
          fail_if_not_ssl: true
          ip_protocol_fallback: false
          method: GET
          no_follow_redirects: false
          preferred_ip_protocol: ip4
          valid_http_versions:
            - HTTP/1.1
            - HTTP/2.0
      http_post_2xx:
        prober: http
        http:
          method: POST
          no_follow_redirects: true
      tcp_connect:
        prober: tcp
      pop3s_banner:
        prober: tcp
        tcp:
          query_response:
          - expect: "^+OK"
          tls: true
          tls_config:
            insecure_skip_verify: false
      grpc:
        prober: grpc
        grpc:
          tls: true
          preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
      grpc_plain:
        prober: grpc
        grpc:
          tls: false
          service: "service1"
      ssh_banner:
        prober: tcp
        tcp:
          query_response:
          - expect: "^SSH-2.0-"
          - send: "SSH-2.0-blackbox-ssh-check"
      irc_banner:
        prober: tcp
        tcp:
          query_response:
          - send: "NICK prober"
          - send: "USER prober prober prober :prober"
          - expect: "PING :([^ ]+)"
            send: "PONG ${1}"
          - expect: "^:[^ ]+ 001"
      icmp:
        prober: icmp
```

AND

```
  modules:
    http_2xx:
      prober: http
      timeout: 2s
      http:
        follow_redirects: true
```

with following scrap config

```
      - job_name: 'blackbox'
        scrape_interval: 60s
        metrics_path: /probe
        params:
          module: [http_2xx]
        static_configs:
         - targets:
            - https://example1.com
            - https://example2.com
        relabel_configs:
         - source_labels: [__address__]
           target_label: __param_target
         - source_labels: [__param_target]
           target_label: instance
         - target_label: __address__
           replacement: blackbox-exporter:9115 # The blackbox exporter.
```

blackbox return following status code

```
probe_http_status_code{instance="https://example1.com", job="blackbox"}
200
probe_http_status_code{instance="https://example2.com", job="blackbox"}
403
```

If I add `www.` to hostname it returns

```
probe_http_status_code{instance="https://www.example1.com", job="blackbox"}
403
probe_http_status_code{instance="https://www.example2.com", job="blackbox"}
200
```

Whats wrong in the redirect ?